# hypothesis test for the two percentages implies the result of the test for the overall percentage

Tags: statistics

[image]

I am asked to test the hypothesis that the percentage of boys who smoked regularly did not change over time, then test that of girls, and then of all.

I used F test for linear regression. I tested the slope

> $$H_0: β_1 = 0  \quad vs  \quad H_1: β_1 ≠ 0$$

I performed the following in **R** and found the p-value for each of them.

> y = c(1982, 1984,.....,2003)
>
> x = c(24,28...,26)
>
> summary(lm(y~x))

And to analyse for girls I changed x for girls and similarly for all.

> All tests give me the result to accept the null hypothesis (i.e. the percentage of boys/girls who smoked did not change overtime )

**Why does the test results for boys and for girls implies the test result for the overall percentage??**
Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: No, because it's not true. For example, you could have data for which you 'accept' 0 slope for Boys and also for Girls, but you reject for Both.

Comment: but in my case, we do not reject $H_0$ for boys and girls, it is not surprising to see that we reject $H_0$ for all, right? why is it?

Comment: Maybe surprising to you, but certainly not impossible. 'All' has more info,  and maybe 'All' is more nearly linear with time. Also you should use 'years since 1980' or something similar, instead of actual year numbers, which are quite large and may cause difficulty in whatever regression program you're using. [If you want us to check your work, someone might do it, provided you put data into a format that's easy to capture. I for one am not going to type the data into R from your table. Also, if you suspect problem with R code, you might post the questionable part of thw session.]